# Display by Category in Admin

Tags: plugins, posts, categories

I run a website that has different online courses. Each course is a post. Each category is a state in which the course is approved. The states change every few months. I am given a document that lists the state and then the courses approved in that state.

Currently, I have to go into each course and then turn on and off the appropriate states which can cause a major headache. I am trying to find a way to easily (in the admin area) display the posts and categories as a matrix to easily turn things on and off.